# Why does the input (colorPicker) only support Hex?

Tags: php, input, typo3, rgba, typo3-11.x

I'm afraid I don't understand why there is no system-side option to select RGB, including transparencies? Am I making a mistake in using it, or did this feature not make it into Typo3 11 either? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not a feature that's requested a lot and in most cases the current functionality is good enough. If you want it added to the TYPO3 core (12, since 11 is already in a feature freeze), add a feature request to https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues.

You can however get the same effect now by adding 2 fields, one with a color picker to select the color and 1 to select the transparency. You'll then have to convert the hex to int and combine the values. If you're using an Extbase model, that could be something like:

```php
list($r, $g, $b) = array_map(
    "hexdec",
    str_split(
        $myModelObject->getColor(),
        strlen( $color ) / 3
    )
);
$rgb = sprintf('rgba(%s, %s, %s, %s)', $r, $g, $b, $myModelObject->getOpacity());
```